# Rspec can't execute simple spec in existing RailsApp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have existing RailsApp in rails v4.0.9

my team develop with some gem and config several file in folder `initializers`

and i need to build test framework using Rspec , this is my Gemfile :

```
group :development, :test do
  gem "rspec-rails", "~> 3.1.0"
  gem "factory_girl_rails", "~> 4.4.1" , :require => false
end

group :test do
  gem "faker", "~> 1.4.3"
  gem "capybara", "~> 2.4.3"
  gem "database_cleaner", "~> 1.3.0"
  gem "launchy", "~> 2.4.2"
  gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.43.0"
end
```

i just tried build Model Spec, the name model is `cart` and first i type very simple spec just for makesure Rspec is running correctly :

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Cart do
    it "has a valid factory for Cart"
end
```

and in `spec/factories/cart.rb` :

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :cart do
        user_id { Faker::Number.number(3) }
    end
end
```

when i type in console `rspec spec/models/cart_spec.rb` :

```
config/initializers/cassandra.rb:25:in `initialize': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from config/initializers/cassandra.rb:59:in `new'
    from config/initializers/cassandra.rb:59:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from lib/cassandra_utils/connector.rb:13:in `configure'
    from config/initializers/cassandra.rb:58:in `<top (required)>'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
    from .rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activesupport-4.0.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
```

how can i solved this ?

thx

Comment: Look in `config/initializers/cassandra.rb:25` and see why the thing you are calling [] on is nil....

Comment: it's contact_point for cassandra :

`@hosts = (ENV['IC_CONTACT_POINTS'] || cassandra_config['IC_CONTACT_POINTS']).to_s.split(',')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ENV['IC_CONTACT_POINTS']
```

returns falsey value, thus `cassandra_config['IC_CONTACT_POINTS']` is evaluated.

`cassandra_config` is `nil`. Amend it and you'll be fine.

Comment: where file i should type this ?

Comment: Did you set the environment variable?

Comment: you should either set up the `IC_CONTACT_POINTS` env variable, or create the `cassandra_config` whatever it is.

Comment: yes...i have cassandra.yml for env variabel config `IC_CONTACT_POINTS`

but it's still not read when run test...when i rails s, server running correct

Comment: my mistak...i forgot set ENV test for my cassandra.yaml